# Microsoft Graph API - File Download - How to use library and subsite paths instead of ids?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

### Main Problem

I am using Microsoft Graph to access SharePoint resources and I'm having trouble understanding why my syntax isn't working when I try to access a specific file.

My SharePoint is structured like this:

```
[domain]
- site
  - subsite
    - library
      - file1.pdf
```

I am able to access a file using the following: (this works)

`sites/{SITE_HOSTNAME},{SITE_ID},{SUBSITE_ID}/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/root:/{FILENAME}:/content`

However, **I would like to access the file using only site, library, and file names (or paths), *instead of using ids*.** Ideally something like this would work: (this does not work)

`sites/{SITE_HOSTNAME}:/sites/{SITE_NAME}/{SUBSITE_NAME}/{LIBRARY_NAME}/{FILENAME}:/content`

Is anything like this possible?

---

### More details...

I seem to be running into at least two problems:

**1. I am unable to access the library as a `drive` in the same way using site paths as using site ids.** E.g.:

```
# these work as expected 
sites/{SITE_HOSTNAME},{SITE_ID},{SUBSITE_ID}/drives/{DRIVE_ID}
sites/{SITE_HOSTNAME}:/sites/{SITE_NAME}/{SUBSITE_NAME}:/drives

# this does not work
sites/{SITE_HOSTNAME}:/sites/{SITE_NAME}/{SUBSITE_NAME}:/drives/{DRIVE_ID}
```

*Why am I unable to access a specific DRIVE_ID in this way?*

**2. As a workaround, I can access the library as a list instead of a drive ...but then I am unable to get the contents of the list items.** For example:

```
# this works
sites/{S_HOSTNAME}:/sites/{S_NAME}/{SS_NAME}:/lists/{LIB_NAME}/items/{ITEM_ID}

# this does not work (`/content` is not available)
sites/{S_HOSTNAME}:/sites/{S_NAME}/{SS_NAME}:/lists/{LIB_NAME}/items/{ITEM_ID}/content
```

*Is there a way to get `content` from a list item, the way it can be retrieved from a drive item?*

Maybe I'm missing something about how path-based and id-based endpoints are supposed to work together? None of the examples in the documentation are much help.